# Need to operate ac appliances using 5V, 10A relay module with ESP8266 node MCU. How to do it. Please explain the schematics elaborately?

Tags: ac, relay, esp8266, switching, appliances

I am having problem in triggering the 5V relay with the output GPIO pin of ESP8266 node MCU. I think the voltage provided by the output GPIO pin is not enough to trigger the relay. I'm thinking of turning of the a AC operating light using the relay. How to do please explain. Can we replace the relay with any transistor circuit to operate the same? Please explain elaborately with the schematics.

Comment: A schematics would be highly appreciated. We can't help you if we don't see what your are doing. Since controlling a relay is something easy you must do something obviously wrong or if not relay might be defective.

Comment: Include a schematic with **all** details, relay model, transistor model etc. everything.  There needs to be only one small detail you might have missed that will make this not work. A common mistake for example is not including the flyback diode. Then your circuit will work once or a few times and then the transistor is destroyed. Don't comment: Oh, but I included a diode. Instead, show the schematic. It sounds like you're not even using a transistor? **Why?** Everyone else does.

Comment: Since you are willing to replace the relay, I'd suggest you find an AC mains voltage coil relay (they exist) and use a MOC30x3 IC between the esp8266  and the relay coil. You get opto isolation, easy operation, and the relay coil doesn't require a separate supply rail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're switching AC, you can't have a transistor alone.  But what you probably need is a transistor boosting the current to the relay.  A normal GPIO pin on a microcontroller isn't intended to drive a relay.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffnzjE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Don't provide 5v power to relay from ESP8266 instead provide 5v from another source i.e 5v smps and switch through gpio pin of ESP8266. Then check if your NO contact of relay changes to NC,if it works fine - after that connect load .

Comment: Are you sure the BC547 is enough to drive the relay, of which we have no specs? Are you sure the 1N4007 is a suitable diode for suppressing the relay kickback? Are you even sure a simple diode is fast enough to suppress the kickback, because better and faster circuits exist? Slow suppression of the kickback will slow the relay opening and the relay contacts arc longer, so they degrade faster and may even weld together. Are you also sure the relay will be off, if/when the ESP8266 has pull-up enabled? Blindly using this schematic to drive AC mains appliances may not be safe.

Comment: @Justme,yes i have implemented same with my aurdino and it works fine for switching 230v ac bulb ,that why i provided as a demo to refer.